# Makefile using $() instead of `` backticks

Tags: shell, make, escape-characters

How do I properly escape a the shell expansion syntax `$()` in a Makefile?

```bsh
.PHONY: test
test:
        @if [ `find myDir -type f -not -name '*.openapi.yaml' | wc -l ` != 0 ]; then \
                echo "All files must end with '.openapi.yaml'";                           \
                find myDir -type f -not -name '*.openapi.yaml';                      \
                exit 42;                                                                  \
        fi
```

When I try modify that to,

```
@if [ $( find myDir -type f -not -name '*.openapi.yaml' | wc -l ) != 0 ]; then \
```

I get,

```
/bin/sh: line 0: [: !=: unary operator expected
```

If I try to escape the `$` with `\$` I get the same error,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need double `$`:

```
.PHONY: test test1 test2

test: test1 test2

test1:
    @echo test1; if [ $$(echo 0) == "0" ]; then echo true; else echo false; fi

test2:
    @echo test2; if [ $$(echo 0) == "1" ]; then echo true; else echo false; fi
```

And an example run:

```
$ make
test1
true
test2
false
```